# How to send GET request to rails from javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I've been googling all day and still couldn't find any answers.So basically in my javascript function, I want to send a GET request to my rails controller and the rails controller will send back a JSON object. Any idea how do I do this? thnx

Answer (score 9):

Using jQuery I would do something like this:

In the selector and event you want, for instance on clicking some element:

> ```
> $(function() {
>   $('#foo').click( function(){
>     var params = '{"field1": "value1", "field2: "value2"}'; 
>     $.get('/controller/bar', params, function(data){ 
>       alert(data); 
>     });
>   });
> });
> ```

Then in your Rails controller:

> ```
> def bar
>   /// hack hack hack
>   render :json => {"response" => "OK"}
> end
> ```

The in your routes.rb:

```
  match 'controller/bar' => 'controller#bar'
```

Finally, change "controller" according to your code. Firebug is your friend!

Comment: Im sorry im still a newby, so after rails sent the JSON object, how can I access that data in my javascript?

Comment: @mamonluk you can access the data through the data variable, for instance data.response would be "OK" - you can try it with  alert(data.response); - or if you want to show it in the HTML itself in a "response" ID you can do something like $('#response').html(data.response);

Answer (score 5):

you can use jQuery ajax to make `get` or `post` request from javascript.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "url to controller method", // it should be mapped in routes.rb in rails
  type: "GET",
  data: {field1 :value1, field2:value2}, // if you want to send some data.
  dataType: "json"
  success: function(data){
  // data will be the response object(json)
  }
});
```

response from rails will something similar to the below, you can modify as per your requirement.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render :json => @json_data }
end
```

Comment: How would rails sent the JSON object back to the javascript then? thnx